# Problem with rendering post host profile picture in DJango template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to render a Django template with different post made by several users. In each individual post, I want to display the profile picture of the person whom created the post. For some reason, the template renders with the posts in full display but without the profile picture.

I have tried to display profile pictures using absolut URL and it works fine, but it does not work dynamically when I try to access the profile picture in the database.

Also, I have made sure that there are profile pictures in the database by uploading pictures from the admin panel.

Here are my codes.

Model:

```
class Member(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):

    # Fields for sign up page
    username = models.CharField(
        _("Användarnamn"), max_length=50, unique=True, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(
        _("Mail"), max_length=100, unique=True, default='')
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Ålder"), null=True, blank=False)
    country = models.CharField(_("Land"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    county = models.CharField(_("Län"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_("Stad"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    sex = models.CharField(_("Kön"), max_length=50,
                           null=True, blank=True, choices=sex_choices)
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        _("Profilbild"), upload_to="static/user_profile_pics", null=True, blank=True)
    account_created = models.DateTimeField(
        _("Medlem sedan"), null=True, auto_created=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(
        _("Senast inloggad"), null=True, auto_created=True)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    count = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)


class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(
        _("Ämne"), max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name


class Room(models.Model):

    # Fields for the adds

    member = models.ForeignKey(
        Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(_("Kategori"),
                                null=True, blank=False, choices=topics, max_length=50, default="")
    title = models.CharField(
        _("Rubrik"), max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)

    country = models.CharField(
        _("Land"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
    county = models.CharField(_("Län"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(_("Stad"), max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(
        _("Beskrivning"), null=True, blank=False, max_length=300)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_("Uppdaterad"), auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_("Skapad"), auto_now=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    count = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-updated", "-created"]
```

Template:

```
{% for room in rooms %}
          <div class="rooms_container shadow p-3 mb-4 bg-body-tertiary rounded d-flex align-content-start flex-column" id="rooms_container">
            
            <div class="profile-img d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              {% if room.member.avatar %}
                  <img src="{{ room.member.member.avatar.url }}" alt="{{ room.member.username }}" class="profile-img-user border float-start rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
              {% else %}
                {% if room.member.sex == "Man" %}
                  <img src="{% static '/user_profile_pics/default-man.jpg' %}" alt="{{ room.member.username }}" class="profile-img-user border float-start rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
                {% elif room.member.sex == "Kvinna" %}
                  <img src="{% static '/user_profile_pics/default-woman.jpg' %}" alt="{{ room.member.username }}" class="profile-img-user border float-start rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
                {% else %}
                  <img src="{% static '/user_profile_pics/default-other.jpg' %}" alt="{{ room.member.username }}" class="profile-img-user border float-start rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
                {% endif %}
              {% endif %}
              <small class="fs-4">{{room.created|timesince}} sedan</small>
            </div>

            <div class="my-2">
              <a href="{% url 'main_app:roomdetail' slug=room.slug %}" id="rooms_title" class="text-black text-decoration-none p-0 m-2 fs-2">{{room.title}}</a>
            </div>
            <textarea disabled cols="15" rows="3" class="p-3 fs-3">{{room.description|truncatechars:150}}</textarea>
            <div class="border-bottom d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
              <ul class="d-flex list-unstyled flex-wrap">
                <li class="mx-3 mt-2 fs-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span class="material-symbols-outlined pe-2" title="Land">flag</span> {{room.country}}</li>
                <li class="mx-3 mt-2 fs-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span class="material-symbols-outlined pe-2" title="Län">location_on</span> {{room.county}}</li>
                <li class="mx-3 mt-2 fs-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><img src="{% static '/images/icons/city.svg' %}" alt="Stad" title="Stad" class="pe-2"> {{room.city}}</li>
              </ul>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  <span title="Antal visningar" class="material-symbols-outlined">visibility</span>
                  <small class="p-0 px-2 m-0">456</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
{% endfor %}
```

CBV:

```
class RoomPageListView(ListView):
    model = Room
    template_name = 'main_app/roomspage.html'
    paginate_by = 3
    context_object_name = "rooms"

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Using select_related to fetch related Member objects along with Room objects
        return Room.objects.select_related('member').all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["category"] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

Settings:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     BASE_DIR / "static"
# ]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```